# Can you copy a website?

Tags: web, copy, c1-cms

Can you copy a Composite C1 website? I would like to create a copy of an existing website as a new website.

I start by creating Site A. Then I want to copy it and create Site B.

For example: copy the pages, functions, data, content, layouts, css from website A to website B. The only difference between the two would be the name.

Comment: Check this tool [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

Comment: This question is formulated far too broadly, attracts useless answers and should be deleted. It serves no purpose. Apart from that the answer is a clear NO, you cannot copy in particular the "functions" and the "data" since they are server-side and you as a user have no access to them. *If* you are not a user but an admin then this question is even more pointless.

Answer (score 2):

It would infringe copywrites and may get you sued, but yes, its possible with a scraper, which basicly get all of the site, and download it to you, such things are used by google and search engines for a cache of sites.

Some exaples:

```
http://www.grepsr.com/?adwords2&gclid=CIe4rrPF57cCFURcpQodASIAgg

http://info.kapowsoftware.com/WebScrapingDefinitiveGuide.html?pi_ad_id=11920224743&gclid=CPCfxbTF57cCFWNNpgodnCQAKQ

http://scrapy.org/
```

or just google "web scrapers"

If you own the site however, and have access to the ftp, just simply copy the files to a folder called `/b` and it can become `www.a.com/b` or you can set up an addon domain to point to /b and make the addon domain.... say `www.b.com`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I failed to mention that I want to copy a Composite C1 CMS website that I created myself.

Comment: do you have root access? Is your site hosted on a service you own?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question "can you copy a website?"

Is Yes....you can.

Provided you have access to all the files/folders, its no different then copying a bunch of folders on your computer, to another folder.

So if you're using a shared host....and everything is in your public_html folder.

Just put the whole website in one folder, then copy it over to another folder.

And then just simply point your new domain to that folder, through your hosting platform.

The process to do this is different for different hosts, but the actual answer to your question is...

YES....YOU CAN COPY A WEBSITE FROM ONE FOLDER TO ANOTHER

Answer (score 0):

IF you have access to the files on the server you can simply copy it to the other desired location...

But remember you have to update links and other paths (if they are absolute).

If you don't have the access you could maybe use the developer tools like firebug, or using F12 on chrome or IE and copy each file and source code you have by hand. This approach is a little more time consuming than the last one but at least it can be made.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the easiest way would be use use Internet Explorers save to offline webpage function (if it is still there) - this will copy all the resources of the currently open webpage and recode the HTML to use them, as for an entire website..I dont think it will be easy, for legal reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your own site, sure why not! Who is there to stop you?

But if it's someone elses site, of course you have to worry about copyright and most of the time the website uses server side scripts which are not downloabeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate a Composite C1 website by copying the entire file structure to a new folder and then update the installation id in the folder `~/App_Data/Composite/Configuration/InstallationInformation.xml` (put in a new random GUID). Then point a new IIS site into this new folder.

If your site is using SQL Server as a backend you also need to create a copy of your database, create a new user account with dbo access for this database and update the connection string in ~/web.config.

If you wish to duplicate an entire page structure inside the existing instance of the CMS and share media files, templates etc. this could be done, but no tooling is available. This would be a coding task.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the the directory(website physical path) where the website is pointing to and paste it somewhere...create a new website and point it to that copied directory....